# Variation of edge-disjoint spanning trees

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithms, search-problem, spanning-tree

In a directed graph, I want to find 2 edge-disjoint spanning trees (arborescence), with the extra restrictions that edges in the 1st tree are not forward arcs in the 2nd tree. Are there existing algorithms I can use, or efficient modifications to existing algorithms?

Comment: Thanks! I change the description.

Comment: I updated the description. Both trees are arborescence. Sorry for the confusion. I am not a CS theorist, so I might have used some amateur words.

Comment: The additional restriction seems difficult to enforce. Perhaps the problem is NP-Complete but one has to spend some time to find a reduction.